# How to allocate memory for an array of pointers within a structure?

Tags: c, pointers, structure, allocation, unions

I have these structures:

```
struct generic_attribute{
    int current_value;
    int previous_value;
};

union union_attribute{
    struct complex_attribute *complex;
    struct generic_attribute *generic;
};

struct tagged_attribute{
    enum{GENERIC_ATTRIBUTE, COMPLEX_ATTRIBUTE} code;
    union union_attribute *attribute;
};
```

I keep getting segmentation fault errors because I am not allocating memory properly when creating an object of type `tagged_attribute`.

```
struct tagged_attribute* construct_tagged_attribute(int num_args, int *args){
    struct tagged_attribute *ta_ptr;
    ta_ptr = malloc (sizeof(struct tagged_attribute));
    ta_ptr->code = GENERIC_ATTRIBUTE;
    //the problem is here:
    ta_ptr->attribute->generic = malloc (sizeof(struct generic_attribute));
    ta_ptr->attribute->generic = construct_generic_attribute(args[0]);
    return  ta_ptr;
}
```

`construct_generic_attribute` returns a pointer to a `generic_attribute` object. I want `ta_ptr->attribute->generic` to contain a pointer to a `generic_attribute` object. This pointer to a `generic_attribute` object is output by the `construct_generic_attribute` function.

What would be the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allocate space for the `attribute` member too.

```
struct tagged_attribute* construct_tagged_attribute(int num_args, int *args)
{
    struct tagged_attribute *ta_ptr;
    ta_ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct tagged_attribute));
    if (ta_ptr == NULL)
        return NULL;
    ta_ptr->code = GENERIC_ATTRIBUTE;
    ta_ptr->attribute = malloc(sizeof(*ta_ptr->attribute));
    if (ta_ptr->attribute == NULL)
     {
        free(ta_ptr);
        return NULL;
     }
    /* ? ta_ptr->attribute->generic = ? construct_generic_attribute(args[0]); ? */
    /* not sure this is what you want */

    return  ta_ptr;
}
```

and you should not `malloc()` for the attribute and then reassign the pointer, in fact your union should not have poitner, because then it doesn't serve any purpose at all, it's a `union` where both members are pointers.

This would make more sense

```
union union_attribute {
    struct complex_attribute complex;
    struct generic_attribute generic;
};
```

so you would set the union value like

```
ta_ptr->attribute.generic = construct_generic_attribute(args[0]);
```

Comment: Many thanks! I get everything except... So... The reason I made a union of two different pointers is that... I have constructors for generic_attribute and complex_attribute which output pointers, as to avoid the entire object being copied in memory. So construct_generic_attribute creates an attribute and allocates space for it. It then outputs a pointers, so as to not output the entire object. Then, the ta_ptr->attribute->generic is assigned to that pointer instead of that object.

Comment: If I do what you said, ta_ptr->attribute.generic = construct_generic_attribute.... then construct_generic_attribute has to output an object.  Right? (Sorry I might be misunderstanding)

Comment: @RebeccaK375 not an object because that concept doesn't exists in c, but you do have to return a copy of the struct.